# Examples of non-compact operators $T$ and $S$ with $M_T=\emptyset$ and $M_S\neq \emptyset$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $\mathcal{L}(\mathcal{H})$ be the space of all linear and bounded operators on a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ and let $\mathcal{K}(\mathcal{H})$ stand for a subspace of $\mathcal{L}(\mathcal{H})$ consisting of all compact operators. For a given $T\in \mathcal{L}(\mathcal{H})$, we denote $$M_T :=\{ x\in S_\mathcal{H} :\| Tx\| =\| T\|\};$$ the set of points from the unit sphere at which $T$ attains its norm. It has been shown that if $T$ is a compact operator, then   $M_T\neq \emptyset$.

I was wondering if someone could give me examples of non-compact operators $T$ and $S$ with $M_T=\emptyset$ and $M_S\neq \emptyset$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The identity operator will fulfill one of those requirements, naturally. (I assume we are in infinite-dimensional space, otherwise every such operator will be compact)

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer Thanks for the comment. Yes, here $\dim (\mathcal{H})$ is infinite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $T: \ell^{2} \to \ell^{2}$ by $T(x_n)=((1-\frac 1 {2n}) x_n)$. Then $\|T\|=1$ but $\|(x_n)\|=1, \|T(x_n)\|=1$ imply $\sum x_n^{2}=1%$ and $\sum (1-\frac 1 {2n})^{2}x_n^{2}=1$ which is impossible since $(1-\frac 1 {2n})^{2} <1$ for all $n$. $T$ is not compact because $(T(e_n))$ has no convegent subsequence.

For the second one you can take $S=I$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and help.